# The RemoveAt method seems to remove the desired value but the update is not being made in the database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2010

I want to retrieve the data from a table in the database into a `Datatable` and I would like to delete a few rows from the `Datatable` based on the values and update the changes made to the `Datatable` in the database.

I have been using the below code for deleting.

```
        DataTable dt_table = new DataTable();

        SqlConnection conn=new SqlConnection(connectionStr);
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM RT_Table", conn);

        SqlDataAdapter sqlda = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);

        conn.Open();

        sqlda.Fill(dt_table);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt_table.Rows.Count; i++)
        {
            if (dt_table.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString()=="TEST")
            {
                dt_table.Rows.RemoveAt(i);
            }
        }

        sqlda.Update(dt_table);
```

The `RemoveAt` method seems to remove the desired value but the update is not being made in the database.

I have been able to perform the `INSERT` into the Datatable and was able to update the table in the Database. For insert I used `InsertCommand`.

Comment: Check your `DeleteCommand`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you should create an `SqlCommandBuilder` that provides the `DeleteCommand` required by the adapter to execute the delete, then you should use the `Delete()` method on the row, not `RemoveAt()`.

The two methods have different meaning and purposes

```
    SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(sqlda);
    foreach(DataRow row in dt_table.Rows)
    {
        if (row["Name"].ToString()=="TEST")
        {
            row.Delete();
        }
    }
    sqlda.Update(dt_table);
```

`Delete()` marks the row with the `DataRowState.Deleted` flag and then when you call `Update()` the `DeleteCommand` of the `DataAdapter` should be able to retrieve the rows marked with that flag and remove them from the database table.  Instead the method `RemoveAt(i)` marks the row with the mentioned flag, but immediately calls `AcceptChanges()`. This method removes the row with `DataRowState.Deleted` from the in memory Rows collection. Thus, when you call the `Update()` method there is no row with the `DataRowState.Deleted` and the DeleteCommand is not executed.

Comment: Your solution is totally right but not your reason. From MSDN: `Calling RemoveAt is the same as calling Delete and then calling AcceptChanges.` The devil lies in that `AcceptChanges`.

Comment: You are right @Alireza never noticed that point in the docs. Yes that AcceptChanges has fooled me more than one time

Comment: It's nearly killed me once!

Comment: Thanks @Steve. Your answer helped. I was able to delete rows from the table in the database.

Comment: I am facing another issue. At times I have to delete the rows from the DataTable that I have inserted into the DataTable (these rows are not retrieved from the database). At such times I get an exception System.InvalidOperationException: Collection was modified; enumeration operation might not execute.

Comment: I suggest to post a new question clearly explaining and showing the code that cause the error. In this way you will attract the attention of more users on your new question